# LUIS entity not recognised

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I trained my `luis` model to recognize an intent called "`getDefinition`" with example utterances such as: `"What does BLANK mean"` or `"Can you explain BLANK to me?"`. It recognizes the intent correctly. I also added an entity called `"topic"` and trained it to recognize what topic the user is asking about. The problem is that luis only recognizes the exact topic the user is asking about if I used that specific term in one of the utterances before.

Does this mean I have to train it with all the possible terms a user can ask about or is there some way to have it recognize it anyway?

For example when I ask `"What does blockchain mean"` it correctly identifies the `entity` (topic) as blockchain because the word blockchain is in the utterance. But if I ask the same version of the question about another topic such as "`what does mining mean"`, it doesn't recognize that as the `entity`.

Using a list or phrase list doesn't seem to be solving the problem. I want to eventually have thousands of topics the bot responds to, entering each topic in a list is tedious and inconvenient. Is there a way LUIS can recognize that its a topic just from the context?

What is the best way to go about this?

Same Doubt, Bit Modified. Sorry for Reposting [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/07d6b905-0072-4bce-871d-0c04b04da28a/luis-entity-not-recognized?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/07d6b905-0072-4bce-871d-0c04b04da28a/luis-entity-not-recognized?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/07d6b905-0072-4bce-871d-0c04b04da28a/luis-entity-not-recognized?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/07d6b905-0072-4bce-871d-0c04b04da28a/luis-entity-not-recognized?forum=LUIS) here.

Comment: How many different values have you tagged in your model for the entity topic? LUIS will be able to manage unknown values, but must be trained correctly

Comment: Do you mean creating a List entity with multiple values? but its a closed set of values. Also here the entoty type is 'Simple.'

Comment: No, I mean an entity of type "Simple". You have to tag sample values that are in your utterances to link to this entity. How many have you tagged? Are these tagged values various or always the same value?

Comment: Also how can we add multiple values to entity while creating the utterance?

Comment: ok...so we have to create sample utterances of similar kinds like What does blockchain mean?, What does Data mining mean? or what does AI mean? and then train?

Comment: I have tagged 3-4 values and two are same with different utterance and one has different value.

Comment: You should also vary the utterances but yes, the idea is to tag different values. `what does AI mean?` and tag "AI" as topic,  "Can you explain blockchain to me?" and tag "blockchain" as topic, etc etc. Add more samples and it will work

Comment: @NicolasR Let me try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment LUIS cannot extract an entity just based on the the intent. Phrase lists will help LUIS extract tokens that don't have explicit training data. For example training LUIS with the utterance `"What does blockchain mean?"` does not mean that it will extract `"mining"` from `"What does mining mean?"` unless `"mining"` was either included in a phrase list, or a list entity. In addition to what Nicolas R said about tagging different values, another thing to consider is that using words not commonly found (or found at all) in the corpuses that LUIS uses for each culture will likely result in LUIS not extracting the words without assistance (either via Phrase list or list entity).

For example, if you created a LUIS application that dealt with units of measurement, while you might not be required to train it with units such as inch, meter, kilometer or ounce; you would probably have to train it with words like milliradian, parsec, and even other cultural spellings like kilometre. Otherwise these words would most likely not be extracted by LUIS. If a user provided the tokens `"Planck unit"`, LUIS might provide a faulty extraction where it returns `"unit"` as the measurement entity instead of `"Planck unit"`.