# How to make LUIS respond with the matched entity

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am setting up a LUIS service for dutch.

I have this sentence:

*Hi, ik ben igor* -> meaning *Hi, I'm igor*

- Where *Hi* is an simple entity called *Hey*, that can have multiple different values such as (hey, hello, ..) which I specified as a list in the phrases.
- And *Igor* is a simple entity called *Name*

In the dashboard I can see that Igor has been correctly mapped as a *Name entity*, but the retrieved result is the following:

```
    {
        "query": "Hi, ik ben igor",
        "topScoringIntent": {
            "intent": "Greeting",
            "score": 0.462906122
        },
        "intents": [
            {
                "intent": "Greeting",
                "score": 0.462906122
            },
            {
                "intent": "None",
                "score": 0.41605103
            }
        ],
        "entities": [
            {
                "entity": "hi",
                "type": "Hey",
                "startIndex": 0,
                "endIndex": 1,
                "score": 0.9947428
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Is it possible to solve this?** I do not want to make a phrase list of all the names that exist.

Comment: My question is a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685339/luis-entity-not-recognised?rq=1

This does not seem to be possible with LUIS

Comment: Can you post your example utterances? Export the app and copy out the example utterances that have the name entity labeled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to train LUIS to even recognize *asdaasdasd*:

```
{
    "query": "Heey, ik ben asdaasdasd",
    "topScoringIntent": {
        "intent": "Greeting",
        "score": 0.5320666
    },
    "intents": [
        {
            "intent": "Greeting",
            "score": 0.5320666
        },
        {
            "intent": "None",
            "score": 0.236944184
        }
    ],
    "entities": [
        {
            "entity": "asdaasdasd",
            "type": "Name",
            "startIndex": 13,
            "endIndex": 22,
            "score": 0.8811139
        }
    ]
}
```

**To be honest I do not have a great guide on how to do this:**

- Add multiple example utterances with example entity position
- Did this for about 5 utterances
- No phrase list necessary

I'm going to accept this as an answer, but once someone explains in-depth and technically what is happening behind the covers, I will accept that answer.